# Batch parameter not getting correct

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

The user input parameter is not getting set into `checkoutdir` variable.

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set SOURCE=E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
set SVN_REPO_URL=https://192.168.1.35:8443/svn/
set projects=JPO/JPOMobile/branches/2016-05-18 JPO/JPOWEB/branches/20160518
(for %%i in (%projects%) do (
            echo. Going to repository - %%i
            echo. Please provide checkoutdir name
            set /p checkoutdir= 
            echo. Checking out %SVN_REPO_URL%%%i from SVN...
            "%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%%checkoutdir%" /url:"%SVN_REPO_URL%%%i" /closeonend:2 
    )
)
echo.
echo. Operation complete.
```

Problem :
The `checkoutdir` is set to the projects directory name
For first iterarion, it is set to `2016-05-18` that results to path in `E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\2016-05-18`. For second iteration, it is set to `20160518` that results to path in `E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\20160518`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SOURCE=E:\Svncheckout\21MAY2016\"
set "SVN=%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin"
set "SVN_REPO_URL=https://192.168.1.35:8443/svn/"
set "projects=JPO/JPOMobile/branches/2016-05-18 JPO/JPOWEB/branches/20160518"
for %%i in (%projects%) do (
    echo. Going to repository - %%i
    echo. Please provide checkoutdir name
    set /p "checkoutdir=Directory name: "
    echo. Checking out %SVN_REPO_URL%%%i from SVN...
    "%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%!checkoutdir!" /url:"%SVN_REPO_URL%%%i" /closeonend:2
)
echo.
echo. Operation complete.
endlocal
```

It is necessary to reference a variable with delayed expansion using exclamation marks instead of percent signs after enabling delayed expansion.

Open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read all output pages.

The environment variables referenced with percent signs are always expanded on parsing the command line respectively the command block defined with `(` ... `)`.

Comment: Thank you, Mofi for your explanation! I solved it a few mins ago

Answer (score 0):

It worked.I had to change `%checkoutdir%` to `!checkoutdir!`